# Bad value in primary key field

Tags: django, sqlite

I am trying to make migrations but this error appear. I tried to delete data base  file and make migrations but still get this error.
[image]

Comment: Please paste such details as text and format it properly.  Also show the code that is causing the error... referred to in the image you shared.  Explain what "migrations" means.

Comment: Sorry my lap in maintenance now.. migrations is command done to create data base in sqle or apply it to project

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the migrations and your database and try to generate your migrations again. If you have any code in production and you cannot delete your migrations a custom function will have to be done in the last migration maybe.

Comment: I already deleted all migrations and db and still have this error

Comment: I could not understand what last line mean